# Best Way of Travelling Weekly

Tags: air-travel, sweden, norway

I live in Sweden and work in Norway. I fly from Sweden to Norway on Tuesdays and I'm back on Fridays.

- What is the cheapest way to keep this travel routine?
- Is there some travel company, or flight company which allows me to buy a large amount of travel tickets, say 20 return tickets with same departure/return airport, but with a price that is substantially smaller than if I bought it each time?

Obs: I'm only interested in advice related to air-travel. The cities where I live and work are 14h apart by train and 13h apart by car. Also night-train or night-buses are not an option.

Comment: I think there's a duplicate...you can try to do nested tickets. Buy a ticket for Tuesday this week, returning some future week. Then buy a Norway-Sweden-Norway ticket for the next Friday, returning to Norway in a future week.

Comment: Contact the airline. They may or may not have frequent traveller discounts. You might also see if your employer/client has some agreements with the airline, and it might be worthwhile to get to talk to the airline's business services; you might already apply. BTW, the ticketing suggested in another comment may or may not be "illegal" with the airline.

Comment: @mkennedy That suggestion does not make sense here. Most airlines operating in Norway and Sweden (that is SAS and Norwegian) don't offer substantially discounted return tickets. If you buy a return ticket, you essentially pay for two single fares and the total price won't change if you combine the single fares differently.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off topic. SAS offers both multi-journey tickets (in packets of 20, 40, 60, 100 or 200) and periodic unlimited tickets, but the discounted fares are based on the relatively expensive "SAS Plus" fare class. The multi-journey tickets are most likely still quite a bit more expensive than what you pay for the cheaper no-frill tickets.